# Flutter Stripe Google Pay button is not accepted by Google Pay support team

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments, flutter-dependencies, google-pay

I have implemented Google Pay using [Stripe plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe) in my Application and it's working fine in Test mode, but when set the Live mode, So need to submit our App for review. After submission get feedback from the Google Pay support team to use [Google Pay branding button](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/brand-guidelines#payment-buttons). but I'm using the as [Stripe plugin provided Google pay button](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/bbe90604d41c2c51cc0f4a66b7c89fedd2b8d068/example/lib/screens/wallets/google_pay_stripe_screen.dart).

I'm getting this type of [mail](https://prnt.sc/-3CuhbtseuKv) from Google Pay support team.

**So my question is Stripe plugin by provided Google pay button is not full fill all required points for Google pay button.**

Please help me or suggestions on this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/brand-guidelines#payment-buttons and use button provided in link because it's `google  pay's` new policy.

Like as we use to do for `apple login`.

So try with the icons provided in link and you will get approval from `Google Pay` to submit your app for review.